# Npgsql AddWithValue not working?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have the following piece of code

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name LIKE '%@pattern%' OR description LIKE '%@pattern%' OR category LIKE '%@pattern%';";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pattern", pattern);
```

This returns an empty resultset in my code.

But if I type the query in PgAdmin like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
WHERE name LIKE '%otter%' 
   OR description LIKE '%otter%' 
   OR category LIKE '%otter%';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You search for `%@pattern%` string literal. Use string concatentation:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name LIKE '%' || @pattern || '%' OR description LIKE '%' || @pattern ||'%' OR category LIKE '%' || @pattern ||'%';";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pattern", pattern);
```

Anyway expression starting with wildcard is not [SARGable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) so it will have poor performace. Consider using `FULL TEXT INDEX`.

---

When you write your query as:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name LIKE '%@pattern%' OR description LIKE '%@pattern%' OR category LIKE '%@pattern%';";
```

You expect that `@patern` will be replaced with your value with second line. But it is not the case. What it really does is searching for **string literal** `%@pattern%` which of course you don't have in table. That is why you get empty resultset.

When you use string concatenation you will add wildcards (start/end) to your parameter's actual value.

Comment: That's it! I can only accept your answer after 15 minutes though. :/
Would you mind explaining why I have to contatenate the strings?

Comment: Makes sense from hindsight. Thank you!